# Expression Engine not returning results for some items

Tags: search

I have a site at [review.gemalto.com](http://review.gemalto.com) and several articles have "NFC" in the title and body.

However searching for NFC returns zero results.

Other search terms such as "Singapore" and "security" work as expected.

I'm at a loss as to why this is happening. Any ideas?

Comment: Which version of EECMS are you using?

Comment: Are you using any search add-ons or the built in search?

Comment: Version 2.8.1, using the built in search

Answer (score 1):

This could possibly be because of the minimum length of a search string. I'm not 100% certain but I think anything under 4 characters doesn't get indexed/searched.

Does it work for other 3 character strings?

Comment: I thought it was because of this, too, @foamcow, but the minimum length is 3 on #eecms 2.8.1, not 4

Comment: On eecms 2.5.3 is 4, too, not 3.

Comment: Searching for "why" does return a bunch of values so minimum length does not appear to be the problem.

Comment: In that case, are the fields where you have "NFC" set to be searchable? What do you get if you search for "nfc"?

Comment: Running 2.8.1 now, I was running 2.7.x but I've upgraded this and still doesn't appear to solve anything. NFC and nfc both return nothing.